# Update date and time sequence with interval 1 minute MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, mysql-workbench

Example I have table like this:

```
id      Day             time
1       mon       2014-01-09 11:23:00
2       tue       2014-01-07 14:40:00
3       wed       2014-01-08 09:23:00 
4       thu       2014-01-09 12:23:00
```

and I want to change the time column with sequence dan interval 1 minute
and it would be like this:

```
id      Day             time
1       mon       2014-01-16 08:01:00
2       tue       2014-01-16 08:02:00
3       wed       2014-01-16 08:03:00 
4       thu       2014-01-16 08:04:00
```

I try to update like this but doesn't work

```
update schemanot set timenot = ('2014-01-16 08:01:00' + interval 1 minute) where id;
```

can you help me what the syntax?

Comment: is it `MySQL` or `SQL Server` ?

Comment: it's mysql actually

Comment: please update the tag accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update you are running will always give '2014-01-16 08:02:00', since there is no way to dynamically update interval. Use below code which uses rank to update interval dynamically.

```
update schemanot updt
join(
select a.*, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS der_rank
from schemanot a, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
order by a.id
) rnk
on updt.id = rnk.id
set updt.timenot = ('2014-01-16 08:00:00' + interval der_rank minute);
```

[SQL Fiddle Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cc8b38/1)

Comment: what is "@curRank" ?

Comment: It's a variable which is used to hold values of rank. Since MySQL doesn't have any embedded rank function, this is a workaround to achieve that.

Comment: I got this error ---> Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect.

Comment: My table uses the timestamp data type, and you use datetime, will the syntax be different?

Answer (score 0):

How about just using the `id`?

```
update schemanot
    set timenot = ('2014-01-16 08:00:00' + interval id minute) ;
```

If you are concerned about gaps, then a simple way to use variables is:

```
set @rn := 0

update schemanot
    set timenot = ('2014-01-16 08:00:00' + interval (@rn := @rn + 1) minute) 
order by id;
```